# AppDomain AssemblyResolve Event asks for Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.resources

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I wrote a custom AssemblyResolve method to handle assembly in a folder other than exe file. But once it shows missing "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.resources". While I have Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll, I don't have Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.resources.dll. How do i manually load Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.resources?

```
protected Assembly ConfigResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            //This handler is called only when the common language runtime tries to bind to the assembly and fails.

            //Retrieve the list of referenced assemblies in an array of AssemblyName.
            string strTempAssmbPath = "";
            Assembly asm = this.GetType().Assembly;

            var uri = new Uri(Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.CodeBase));


            Assembly objExecutingAssemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            AssemblyName[] arrReferencedAssmbNames = objExecutingAssemblies.GetReferencedAssemblies();

            //Loop through the array of referenced assembly names.
            if (arrReferencedAssmbNames.Any(strAssmbName => strAssmbName.Name == args.Name))
            {
                strTempAssmbPath = Path.Combine(uri.LocalPath, args.Name) + ".dll";
            }
            //Load the assembly from the specified path.                    
            Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(strTempAssmbPath);

            //Return the loaded assembly.
            return myAssembly;  
        }
```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, but I'm not convinced it's actually a dll that exists. There are resources attached to the `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll` library, and maybe for whatever reason those can't be accessed. Looking at it in .NET Reflector, it lists the references, and `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.resources.dll` is not listed. Have you had any luck with this yet?

Answer (score 3):

Issue has been discussed on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526836/wpf-appdomain-assemblyresolve-being-called-when-it-shouldnt).

Proposed solution:
Add the following line to AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.MainAssembly)]
```

Answer (score 2):

We ran into this same problem with an AssemblyResolve event handler. Oddly, we only saw the issue on Windows XP machines. Our application is localized to many languages, so we were hesitant to use the NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute. Our application was compiled for .NET v3.5, but was still being affected by the AssemblyResolve change [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) for .NET v4.0:

> **Important** Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the ResolveEventHandler event is raised for all assemblies, including
>   resource assemblies. In earlier versions, the event was not raised for
>   resource assemblies. If the operating system is localized, the handler
>   might be called multiple times: once for each culture in the fallback
>   chain.

The way we resolved this was to check e.Name and see if it was looking for *.Resources.dll. If that file was not found in the AppDomain or known folder, we would remove ".Resources" and look for *.dll. If that file exists, we load and return that assembly. This resolved the problem for us.